# How to use convert's page parameter with php IMagick?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, pdf-generation, imagick

I need to set the paper size for the resulting pdf file. How do I do it with php's IMagick object? I would use the `page` parameter if I used shell `convert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [imagick](/questions/tagged/imagick) you would use the methods [Imagick::setImagePage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagepage.php).

You would need to look up the proper dimensions to match a specific page-name. See [page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) documents.

```
11x17       792 x 1224
Ledger      1224 x 792
Legal       612 x 1008
Letter      612 x 792
LetterSmall 612 x 792
ArchE       2592 x 3456
ArchD       1728 x 2592
ArchC       1296 x 1728
ArchB       864 x 1296
ArchA       648 x 864
A0          2380 x 3368
A1          1684 x 2380
A2          1190 x 1684
A3          842 x 1190
A4          595 x 842
A4Small     595 x 842
A5          421 x 595
A6          297 x 421
A7          210 x 297
A8          148 x 210
A9          105 x 148
A10         74 x 105
B0          2836 x 4008
B1          2004 x 2836
B2          1418 x 2004
B3          1002 x 1418
B4          709 x 1002
B5          501 x 709
C0          2600 x 3677
C1          1837 x 2600
C2          1298 x 1837
C3          918 x 1298
C4          649 x 918
C5          459 x 649
C6          323 x 459
Flsa        612 x 936
Flse        612 x 936
HalfLetter  396 x 612
```